# Android, Canvas, draw image

Tags: java, android

How would I draw an image on  canvas and position it based on x/Y co-ords? Also, is it possible to check if an image is drawn at those co-ords?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) to get your image from file, or wherever, then
you can use one of the overloads of `Canvas.drawBitmap(...)`] to draw the image on the canvas. One of the overloads takes x/y coordinates.